Sonos SMAPI Endpoint - Can this be decided at runtime?
I am attempting to create a Content service for Jellyfin media server with Sonos, and realise that Sonos needs to know the https location of the SMAPI.
The way my content service works is that users have their own servers running on their own network. Therefore, I would like the SMAPI to be running on the users own network as part of the Jellyfin media server. Each user essentially has their own copy of the SMAPI running.
When creating a sandbox content service, you can see Sonos is asking for the endpoint of the SMAPI - however I wouldn't know this until runtime, as I would intend to ask the user for their Jellyfin endpoint during the content service setup, at which point they would give a fully formed https URL that would reach the Jellyfin server running on their specific network.
I suppose it's not that different to the file server NAS content service where you give a network name and endpoint along with credentials - so this setup would be similar in that the setup of the service derives the SMAPI endpoint?
Is it possible to do this? Or is it expected that the SMAPI is always static and publicly accessible and you cannot make a specific endpoint for a specific content service setup? If that is the case, then you would have one SMAPI for N users? Which is not how I would want to organise the solution?


This kind of thing will only work with the Desktop app, or S1 mobile apps, or third party apps.
Sonos S2 mobile apps do not call SMAPI themselves any more, everything is proxied via their cloud, so your SMAPI endpoint needs to be public (and https) so their cloud service can call it.
